# Why do parts of my reference image go missing when using the pen tool to trace it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

[image: parts of the reference image goes missing when using the pen tool in illustrator]

I placed a reference image in Illustrator that I want to trace. When I use the pen tool, some parts of the reference image go missing in the middle of the process. Why is this happening? What can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

When you are drawing a path, just set the fill to none.  The fill is covering the reference image. You can change it back afterwards.

[image]

Comment: you are a legend man <3